# The PATCH method is not supported for route update/9. Supported methods: POST

Tags: patch, laravel-9

I want to be able to change the status of a form, but when I try to change it, I get an error message saying, 'The PATCH method is not supported for route update/9. Supported methods: POST. Where is the problem?

This is the poliumum view that is used to update the status of the:

```
      <form action="update/{{ $pasien->first()->id }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <table class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>No</td>
              <td>Nama Pasien</td>
              <td>NIK</td>
              <td>Usia</td>
              <td>Kelamin</td>
              <td>No Telefon</td>
              <td>Alamat</td>
              <td>Poli</td>
              <td>Status</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          @foreach ($pasien as $pasien)
            <tr>
              <td>{{ $pasien->id }}</td>
              <td>{{ $pasien->namapasien }}</td>
              <td>{{ $pasien->nik }}</td>
              <td>{{ $pasien->usia }}</td>
              <td>{{ $pasien->jeniskelamin }}</td>
              <td>{{ $pasien->nohp }}</td>
              <td>{{ $pasien->alamat }}</td>
              <td>{{ $pasien->kategori }}</td>
              <td>

                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn
                    @if ($pasien->status == 'Diterima') btn-warning
                    @elseif ($pasien->status == 'Mengantri') btn-secondary
                    @elseif ($pasien->status == 'Selesai') btn-success
                    @elseif ($pasien->status == 'Cancelled') btn-danger
                    @endif
                    btn-sm dropdown-toggle py-0 px-2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    @if ($pasien->status == 'Diterima')
                    Diterima
                    @elseif ($pasien->status == 'Mengantri')
                    Mengantri
                    @elseif ($pasien->status == 'Selesai')
                    Selesai
                    @elseif ($pasien->status == 'Cancelled')
                    Cancelled
                    @endif
                  </button>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <form action="update/{{ $pasien->first()->id }}" method="post">
                      @method('patch')
                      @csrf
                      <input type="hidden" name="status" value="Mengantri">
                      <button type="submit" class="dropdown-item">Mengantri</button>
                    </form>
                    <form action="update/{{ $pasien->first()->id }}" method="post">
                      @method('patch')
                      @csrf
                      <input type="hidden" name="status" value="Selesai">
                      <button type="submit" class="dropdown-item">Selesai</button>
                    </form>
                    <form action="update/{{ $pasien->first()->id }}" method="post">
                      @method('patch')
                      @csrf
                      <input type="hidden" name="status" value="Cancelled">
                      <button type="submit" class="dropdown-item">Cancelled</button>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          @endforeach
```

Routes web.php:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});

Route::get('/ambilantrean', function () {
    return view('ambilantrean');
})->name('ambilantrean');


Auth::routes();

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'admin']], function () {
    Route::get('/admin', [AdminController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');
    Route::get('/poliumum', [AdminController::class, 'poliumum']);
    Route::get('/poligigi', [AdminController::class, 'poligigi']);
    Route::get('/politht', [AdminController::class, 'politht']);
});

Route::get('/antrean', [AntreanuserController::class, 'userantreanall'])->name('antreanuserall');
Route::get('/antrean', [AntreanuserController::class, 'userantreanall'])->name('antreanuser');
Route::get('/ambilantrean', [AntreanuserController::class, 'showForm'])->name('ambilantrean.form');
Route::post('/ambilantrean', [AntreanuserController::class, 'store'])->name('ambilantrean.store');
Route::get('/contact', [ContactController::class, 'contact'])->name('contact.show');
Route::post('/contact', [ContactController::class, 'sendEmail'])->name('contact.send');
Route::post('update/{id}', [AntreanController::class, 'update'])->name('update');
```

AntreanController :

```
public function update(Request $request, Antrean $antrean)
{
    $validated = $request->validate([
        "status" => "required|in:Diterima,Mengantri,Selesai,Cancelled",
    ]);
    $antrean->update($validated);
    return back()->with("success", "Status berhasil di perbaharui");
}
```